# Is there a package for calculating and displaying reading time per chapter?

Tags: packages

I would like to display the reading time for a given chapter either in the header, or in the footnotes of a given chapter.

Is there a package for this?

Comment: There are several package to give an approximate word count. Once you have that value: https://blog.medium.com/read-time-and-you-bc2048ab620c